# Split a string into combinations of 2 characters and expand into data frame in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, combinations, plyr

I'm looking for a clean way to take a row from a table and expand it to multiple rows with near identical information except for one of the columns.

Here's an example where I start with this:

```
    sex cat         status      pairs
1   F       6,10    Cancer      6,10
2   F       8,10    Cancer      8,10
3   F      12,13    NoCancer    12,13
4   F   3,4,5,10    Cancer      
5   F       7,10    Cancer      7,10
6   F        4,8    NoCancer    4,8
```

And would like to end up with this:

```
    sex cat         status      pairs
1   F       6,10    Cancer      6,10
2   F       8,10    Cancer      8,10
3   F      12,13    NoCancer    12,13
4   F   3,4,5,10    Cancer      3,4
4   F   3,4,5,10    Cancer      3,5
4   F   3,4,5,10    Cancer      3,10
4   F   3,4,5,10    Cancer      4,5
4   F   3,4,5,10    Cancer      4,10
4   F   3,4,5,10    Cancer      5,10
5   F       7,10    Cancer      7,10
6   F        4,8    NoCancer    4,8
```

Now, I know that I can take a string and easily split it apart and then find all possible combinations of size m.

Something like this:

```
combn(x,2, simplify=F, function(x){ paste(x, collapse=",")} )
```

While I've done something similar to this in which I break down a string into individual elements and then use `plyr` (as suggested by the talented @recology_ via [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9238018))

In my previous example (as can be seen in the gist) the solution ended up being something similar to the following:

```
df <- data.frame(id =c(11,32,37),
                 name=c("rick","tom","joe"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(plyr)
foo <- function(x){
  strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
}
ddply(df, .(id, name), summarise, letters=foo(name))
```

I've been unsuccessful in incorporating the combn() function into this pattern. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: could you use `dput` to include some of your data here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way using data.tables

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
result <- DT[,combn(unlist(strsplit(cat,",")),2,paste,collapse=","),
             by=list(sex,cat,status)]
setnames(result,"V1","pairs")
result
#     sex      cat   status pairs
#  1:   F     6,10   Cancer  6,10
#  2:   F     8,10   Cancer  8,10
#  3:   F    12,13 NoCancer 12,13
#  4:   F 3,4,5,10   Cancer   3,4
#  5:   F 3,4,5,10   Cancer   3,5
#  6:   F 3,4,5,10   Cancer  3,10
#  7:   F 3,4,5,10   Cancer   4,5
#  8:   F 3,4,5,10   Cancer  4,10
#  9:   F 3,4,5,10   Cancer  5,10
# 10:   F     7,10   Cancer  7,10
# 11:   F      4,8 NoCancer   4,8
```

Note that I imported `df` using `stringsAsFacctors=F`, and the `F` for `Female` was interpreted as `FALSE`, so I needed `df$sex <- "F"`, but this shouldn't affect you.

Comment: Thanks. While I try keep dependencies in my code to a low, I had already been using data.table for something else and this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to edit this into @jlhoward's answer, but it got too long. So writing it separately. This answer basically builds over his nice and compact solution (+1), to address possible speed enhancements.

Firstly, `strsplit` is vectorised. Therefore, we could avoid splitting on each row by splitting them up-front first by taking advantage of the fact that `data.table` also allows easy creation and operation of columns of type `list`:

```
DT[, splits := strsplit(cat, ",", fixed=TRUE)]
```

Secondly, if the length of the *splits* is <= 2L, then we don't have to use `combn` - as nothing will change. This should result in more speed-ups proportional to the number of such columns.

```
DT[, { tmp = splits[[1L]]; 
       if (length(tmp) <= 2L) 
           list(pairs=pairs) 
       else 
           list(pairs=as.vector(combn(tmp, 2L, paste, collapse=","))) 
     }, 
by=list(sex, cat, status)]
```

Here are some benchmarks:

#### Prepare functions first:

```
## data.table solution from @jlhoward's
f1 <- function(DT) {
    result <- DT[,combn(unlist(strsplit(cat,",")),2,paste,collapse=","),
                 by=list(sex,cat,status)]
    setnames(result,"V1","pairs")
}

## slightly more efficient in terms of speed
f2 <- function(DT) {
    DT[, splits := strsplit(cat, ",", fixed=TRUE)]
    ans <- DT[, { tmp = splits[[1L]]; 
                 if (length(tmp) <= 2L) 
                   list(pairs=cat) 
                 else 
                   list(pairs=as.vector(combn(tmp, 2L, paste, collapse=","))) 
                },   
           by=list(sex, cat, status)]
}
```

The `dplyr` solution also splits for each group. In addition, the `do.call(rbind, .)` and `data.frame(.)` calls on each group would be really inefficient. I've simplified it to remove some function calls including `do.call(rbind, .)`.

The `data.frame(.)` call however can't be avoided, IIUC, as `do(.)` requires it.. Anyhow, adding the simplified version to the benchmarks as well:

```
f3 <- function(df) {
    twosplit <- function(df,varname = "cat"){
       strsplit(df[[varname]],split = ",")[[1L]] %>% 
       combn(2, paste, collapse=",") %>%
       data.frame(pairs = .)
    }
    df %>% group_by(sex, cat, status) %>% do(twosplit(.))
    # the results are not in the same order.. 
}
```

#### Update: (added @MatthewPlourde's solution as well)

```
f4 <- function(d) {
    pairs <- lapply(strsplit(d$cat, ','), function(x) apply(combn(x, 2), 2, paste, collapse=','))
    new.rows <- mapply(function(row, ps) as.data.frame(c(as.list(row), list(pairs=ps))), 
                   row=split(d, 1:nrow(d)), ps=pairs, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
    do.call(rbind, new.rows)
}
```

#### Prepare data:

```
DT <- rbindlist(replicate(1e4L, df, simplify=FALSE))[, status := 1:nrow(DT)]
DF <- as.data.frame(DT)
```

#### Timings:

```
system.time(ans2 <- f2(DT)) ## 1.3s
system.time(ans1 <- f1(DT)) ## 4.9s
system.time(ans3 <- f3(DF)) ## 212s!
system.time(ans4 <- f4(DF)) ## stopped after 8 mins.
```

---

On a final note: You could avoid using `combn` here (which is really slow), if you're always needing just `nC2`, with your own custom function, which I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this. As this is a one time thing on a not so large data set, speed wasn't really a concern of mine. However, thanks for the great breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach via `dplyr`, heir to the throne of `plyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

twosplit <- function(df,varname = "V2"){
  strsplit(df[[varname]],split = ",") %>%
    unlist %>%
    combn(2, simplify=FALSE, function(x){ paste(x, collapse=",")} ) %>%
    do.call(rbind,.) %>%
    unname %>%
    data.frame(unname(df),pairs = .)
}

df %>%
  group_by(V2) %>%
  do(twosplit(.))

         V2    X1       X2       X3    X4 pairs
1     12,13 FALSE    12,13 NoCancer 12,13 12,13
2  3,4,5,10 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer    NA   3,4
3  3,4,5,10 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer    NA   3,5
4  3,4,5,10 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer    NA  3,10
5  3,4,5,10 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer    NA   4,5
6  3,4,5,10 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer    NA  4,10
7  3,4,5,10 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer    NA  5,10
8       4,8 FALSE      4,8 NoCancer   4,8   4,8
9      6,10 FALSE     6,10   Cancer  6,10  6,10
10     7,10 FALSE     7,10   Cancer  7,10  7,10
11     8,10 FALSE     8,10   Cancer  8,10  8,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution:

```
# define sample data
d <- read.table(text="    sex cat         status      pairs
1   F       6,10    Cancer      6,10
2   F       8,10    Cancer      8,10
3   F      12,13    NoCancer    12,13
4   F   3,4,5,10    Cancer      ''
5   F       7,10    Cancer      7,10
6   F        4,8    NoCancer    4,8", as.is=TRUE)


# add pairs column
pairs <- lapply(strsplit(d$cat, ','), function(x) apply(combn(x, 2), 2, paste, collapse=','))
new.rows <- mapply(function(row, ps) as.data.frame(c(as.list(row), list(pairs=ps))), 
                   row=split(d, 1:nrow(d)), ps=pairs, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
do.call(rbind, new.rows)
#       sex      cat   status pairs pairs.1
# 1   FALSE     6,10   Cancer  6,10    6,10
# 2   FALSE     8,10   Cancer  8,10    8,10
# 3   FALSE    12,13 NoCancer 12,13   12,13
# 4.1 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer           3,4
# 4.2 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer           3,5
# 4.3 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer          3,10
# 4.4 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer           4,5
# 4.5 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer          4,10
# 4.6 FALSE 3,4,5,10   Cancer          5,10
# 5   FALSE     7,10   Cancer  7,10    7,10
# 6   FALSE      4,8 NoCancer   4,8     4,8
```

Comment: That's some pretty impressive juggling of apply functions. Thanks.